# set fn + arrow to represent 'home' and 'end'

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'd like to add set a functionality to the pair fn+right/left to be like in Mac - 'home' and 'end'.
I don't mean to replace the 'home' and 'end' buttons - just adding another 'home'/'end' keys.
The advantage is in writing/modifying text. I use the arrows a lot, and I also use the home and end buttons, but why jump to a whole new button? My left hand is already near the fn (function) key - ready to press control or shift.

How do I set this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I definitely understand why you want to do this! Here's my bet what I have done:

Launch a terminal and run 'xev'. Place your mouse cursor over the Event Tester window and press fn+right/left. You should get a read-out like:

```
    KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
root 0xb2, subw 0x0, time 89989888, (98,124), root:(1007,175),
state 0x0, keycode 171 (keysym 0x1008ff17, XF86AudioNext), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

This is for my keyboard and fn+right. Find the keycode -- here it's 171.

Now go edit your .bashrc file in your home directory. It's hidden, so pres Ctrl+H in Nautilus to show. Then add lines

```
    xmodmap -e "keycode 171 = Home"
    xmodmap -e "keycode xxx = End"
```

where you replace the 171 and xxx with the obtained keycodes. Then save and close the file. Close all your terminals, open one, and you should be ready to go!

Now, there is one draw-back: you have to activate this on every boot. You do that by opening a terminal, and that's it. You can close it again immediately. Or you can try fixing it to do it automatically, [as described here](http://cweiske.de/howto/xmodmap/allinone.html). I just run the terminal using a shortcut and then kill it...

Comment: The keycode for fn+right is the same as just pressing right (without fn). This is problematic, because I don't want to override my right/left key.

Comment: Well, then it may not be a "function key" (or what the correct term is). My arrows are, but they are also media keys. Then I don't know what to do, sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyhow. This is still a great way to change keyboard behavior :)

Comment: You can add a script to the session startup configuration. If you are on GNOME based environment, execute the `gnome-session-properties` command.

Comment: Event tester responds one key at a time. I don't understand how did you manage to get the code for pressing the two together.

Comment: Does the fn key give you read-out? If so, then your keyboard is different from he one I worked with: One that, the fn key + any key with a fn function (it was written in blue, like the "fn" on the fn key) would output one key event, different from  just pressing the key alone. In short, "fn + fn'able key = key". This is not the case for ctrl, alt and shift.

Comment: I cannot see any key output when clicking FN + arrow key. Does that mean that it's not possible to bind there anything ?

Comment: Just like @Jurosh I don't see any output when doing fn+leftarrow either (I'm on an XPS13). Do you have any idea whether that makes it impossible to bind home to fn+leftarrow?

Comment: @Jurosh : Yes, I think it is then impossible. My undocumented thought is that it is not every key that is physically hooked up to provide a new output with Fn. You can try reading through the following, maybe to get search query ideas.

https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/179rrz/make_fn_right_arrow_become_end_key/

Comment: @kramer65 : Thanks for the bump.

Comment: Dear both, I have asked a new question concerning this, which you can follow in case answers come along: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165076/determine-if-fn-key-can-be-made-to-produce-keycode-if-xev-provides-none

Comment: Dear both, an answer has now been provided that you can check. Best,

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ubuntu+Gnome and `xev` does not show anything when you type `Fn+Left` or `Fn+Right` - than you might have an interceptor in Gnome session like I did. Also my hardware laptop keyboard shows `"backward"` and `"forward"` player/music icons for left and right buttons - it means my hardware keyboard sends `keycode 173` for `Fn+Left` and `keycode 171` for `Fn+Right`.

### Disable gnome session listeners

You can disable listeners with UI `dconf-editor`.

Install and run `dconf-editor`.

Go to the following paths and disable `Use default value` and put empty array `[]` in `Custom value`.

For `Fn+Left`:

`/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/previous-static`.

For `Fn+Right`:

`/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/next-static`

Apply changes for both paths and close `dconf-editor`.

### Apply software buttons mapping with xmodmap

Now apply custom handler for `Fn+Left`:

```bsh
xmodmap -e "keycode 171 = End"
```

Before this setting it was for me `xmodmap -pk | grep -i '171'`:

```bsh
171     0x1008ff17 (XF86AudioNext)  0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0x1008ff17 (XF86AudioNext)  0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0x1008ff17 (XF86AudioNext)
```

After this setting:

```bsh
171     0xff57 (End)    0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0xff57 (End)    0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0xff57 (End)
```

Apply custom handler for `Fn+Right`:

```bsh
xmodmap -e "keycode 173 = Home"
```

Before `xmodmap -pk | grep -i '173'`:

```bsh
173     0x1008ff16 (XF86AudioPrev)  0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0x1008ff16 (XF86AudioPrev)  0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0x1008ff16 (XF86AudioPrev)
```

After:

```bsh
173     0xff50 (Home)   0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0xff50 (Home)   0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0xff50 (Home)
```

Now it works for me. However the result is not permanent, after reboot you have to do this again. Some startups scripts to do this do not work nice, because `xmodmap` must be initialized only after some time (when it is ready).

### Apply software buttons mapping with xkb

Turns out that `xmodmap` is outdated and not used anymore in Gnome.

[Permanent solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215062/330374) is to use `xkb`.

Create symbol file `fn_mod` at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` (sudo requires) with following content:

```py
// /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet
// key <I171>   {      [ XF86AudioNext         ]       };
// key <I173>   {      [ XF86AudioPrev         ]       };
//
// /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
// key <HOME> { [  Home         ]   };
// key  <END> { [  End          ]   };
//
// make Fn+Left (keycode 171) act as Home
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "left_as_home" {
    key <I171> { [ End ] };
};

// make Fn+Right (keycode 173) act as End
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "right_as_end" {
    key <I173> { [ Home ] };
};
```

Make backup for following files in case you will brake them:

```bsh
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst
```

Add following content into `evdev.xml` (`<xkbConfigRegistry>` -> `<optionList>` ->):

```xml
    <group allowMultipleSelection="true">
      <configItem>
        <name>fn_mod</name>
        <description>Fn key behavior</description>
      </configItem>
      <option>
        <configItem>
          <name>fn_mod:left_as_home</name>
          <description>Fn+Left (aka XF86AudioPrev) act as Home</description>
        </configItem>
      </option>
      <option>
        <configItem>
          <name>fn_mod:right_as_end</name>
          <description>Fn+Right (aka XF86AudioNext) act as End</description>
        </configItem>
      </option>
    </group>
```

Add following content into `evdev` (Find line `! option =   symbols` and append on the next line):

```py
  fn_mod:left_as_home  = +fn_mod(left_as_home)
  fn_mod:right_as_end  = +fn_mod(right_as_end)
```

Add following content into `evdev.lst` (Find line `! option` and append on the next line):

```
  fn_mod               Fn key behavior
  fn_mod:left_as_home  Fn+Left (aka XF86AudioPrev) act as Home
  fn_mod:right_as_end  Fn+Right (aka XF86AudioNext) act as End
```

`evdev.xml` changes will create UI tweak in `gnome-tweaks`. To check/enable this open `gnome-tweaks` go to the `Keyboard & Mouse` -> `Additional Layout Options` -> `Fn key behavior`.

Finally reboot the session and check in terminal.

```bsh
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,ru,us
variant:    ,,
options:    fn_mod:left_as_home,fn_mod:right_as_end
```

```bsh
$ setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+ru:2+us:3+inet(evdev)+fn_mod(left_as_home)+fn_mod(right_as_end)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Comment: I was afraid of doing such a long workaround. But seriously, it worked flawlessly. Thank you so much. This decision on Dell XPS 9500/9300 is so DUMB. Seriously. they JUST removed these shortcuts. It looks like they don't want to sell these 9500/9300 for developers and power users. Anyways. Thank you.

Comment: I was too fast commenting here. It actually does not help too much since it does not enable by default all combinations of Fn+Arrow, with Ctrl, Shift for instancece

Comment: @leoheck did you managed to make it work for XPS 9500? Home/End still don't want to budge for me

Comment: No, unfortunately I dropped this. Seriously, DELL is doing the worst on these XPS computers. Why the hell they have disable one of its best features?