# Determine if Fn + Key can be made to produce keycode if xev provides none

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xev

In relation to the comments on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/61131/13884), I am curious about the following:

If one does not get a keycode output in the `xev` Event Tester when pressing `Fn + Key`, are there ways to determine whether obtaining a keycode for the combination is possible?

As far as I have understood, some keyboards have the possible options hardcoded, while others might be softcoded. I would like to know if there is some way to determine if one or the other is the case, without decontructing the physical keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `showkey --scancodes` at a text (non-X) console.

My laptop doesn't have a different scancode when using Fn, so I resorted to using the windows key instead.

Comment: Thank you! I used a virtual terminal (Ctrl+Alt+f2) and learned something.