# Increasing brightness with Fn-key outputs symbol ±

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a laptop with a function key <kbd>Fn</kbd> that I use for volume and brightness control.

Whenever I increase the brightness of the screen by the shortcut <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>, the screen increases in brightness but I also get a symbol “±” outputted.

E.g., I'm in the terminal environment, I increase the brightness and a “±” is deposited in my terminal.

I do not have this problem with any of the other shortcut keys that use the function key. Is there any way to stop this from happening?

The only shortcuts in Ubuntu I can find are in the system settings “Settings → Keyboard Shortcuts”, which do not include this instance.

Edit:
I found in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43049/set-fn-arrow-to-represent-home-and-end) that there is a program `xev` which is an event monitor for mouse and keyboard. When I press and release the key combination <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>, I get the following output from `xev`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x6a9, subw 0x0, time 10913753, (1291,-68), root:(1342,47),
    state 0x0, keycode 126 (keysym 0xb1, plusminus), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c2 b1) "±"
    XmbLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c2 b1) "±"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x6a9, subw 0x0, time 10913765, (1291,-68), root:(1342,47),
    state 0x0, keycode 126 (keysym 0xb1, plusminus), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c2 b1) "±"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the X event tester `xev` output:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x6a9, subw 0x0, time 10913765, (1291,-68), root:(1342,47),
    state 0x0, keycode 126 (keysym 0xb1, plusminus), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c2 b1) "±"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I take note of the `keycode 126` and add the line `xmodmap -e "keycode 126 = "` (note that I map it to nothing) to the file `.bashrc` (hidden in the home directory). This has solved my problem, though it is more of a workaround than an actual solution.